# elements do not fit in single line even though width sums to 100%

Tags: html, css, css-float

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/wngf9xy9/

**HTML**:

```
<div class="cont">
    <label class="Label"> Label1 </label>
    <input type="text" class="inp1" maxlength="11">
    <select name="select1" id="select11" class="select1" >
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="value1">value1</option>

    </select>

    <br>

    <label class="Label"> Label2 </label>
    <select name="select2" class="select2" >
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="value2">value2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cont{
    width: 300px;


}
.cont *{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cont label{
    width: 22%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.cont .inp1{
    width: 20%;

    height: 20px;
}
.cont .select1{
    width: 53%; /*fallback*/
    width: calc(58% - 15px);
    margin-left: 15px;  
    height: 18px;
    top: 0px;
}

.cont .select2{

    width: calc(78% - 15px);
    margin-left: 15px;  
    height: 18px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

I have the above HTML/CSS yet for some reason the last select overflows and goes to the second line. I dont understand why this is. They should be able to fit in the single line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inline` and `inline-block` elements considers the whitespace and line breaks as a single space. If you remove the line breaks or comment them out as given below  it'll be aligned in a single line.

```
<div class="cont">
<label class="Label"> Label1 </label><!--
--><input type="text" class="inp1" maxlength="11"><!--
--><select name="select1" id="select11" class="select1" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="value1">value1</option>

</select>
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/wngf9xy9/5/)

In this case we can get around the issue using `float` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/wngf9xy9/6/)

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. Can you recommend a way so that I can achieve my the desired results without having to put all the elements in a single line since this really reduces readability

Comment: @death_relic0 you could use `float` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/wngf9xy9/6/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

same answer as @TJ but without comments Instead, I prefer to close the tag on the next line because html comments are ugly :p

http://jsfiddle.net/wngf9xy9/3/

```
<div class="cont">
    <label class="Label"> Label1 </label
   ><input type="text" class="inp1" maxlength="11"
   ><select name="select1" id="select11" class="select1">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="value1">value1</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label class="Label"> Label2 </label
   ><select name="select2" class="select2">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="value2">value2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you try changing the css for `label` from `inline-block` to `inline`, all the elements will fit in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Use float left to put the elements beside each other. and add a break to align them properly and neatly and you are done.

```
This is the FIDDLE done:
http://jsfiddle.net/ezLe2mfn/
```